# Open URLS starting with chrome://

Tags: python, google-chrome

Might be a stupid question..

But here is my problem, I want to load urls in browser or Python starting with chrome://, opening http:// links have no problems with Python urllib2, any module I may use to make calls to urls starting with chrome://

Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you expect such a URL to do outside of Chrome?

Comment: I was testing something.. and felt the need to load urls starting with chrome:// for certain amount of times. 

It says chrome.. but actually I am doing this in Firefox

Comment: But you *do* realize that ``chrome://`` URI(s) are *specific* to Chrome right? There is *no* way that I can think of that these URI(s) would be remotely useful to anything *bt* Chrome! They are **Chrome URI(s)**; not HTTP/Web Resources or anything.

Comment: I am here trying to analyze certain behavior of Firefox which doesn't look normal. For which I need to call chrome:// URI's which is of course specific to chrome library. I am not trying to pull any web resource. 

Just wondering if Python can help me make such call.. I am not bothered about the Output or what is displays. I just need to make such calls.

Even if I think from Javascript prespective, my problem remains same. How do i make calls which starts with chrome://

Comment: What is particular URL that you use in Firefox , that has 'chrome' in it ?

Comment: Ah, `chrome` URLs do totally different things in Firefox and in Chrome, but in either case, they don't have any meaning outside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As James Mills mentioned, you could use [selenium/webdriver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) instead of urllib2

Comment: Got something here stackoverflow.com/questions/24876649/python-open-chrome-urls?rq=1

But doesnt work with Firefox.. Badluck :(

Returns as False

Comment: chromedriver creates a totally new chrome, you should decorate it as you like